# Can we make series line dashed and smooth at the same time?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I love the [dashed](http://dygraphs.com/tests/per-series.html) line and [plotters](http://dygraphs.com/tests/smooth-plots.html). Now I am thinking about making a dashed series line smoother with a plotter. Seems the plotter is not working if the strokepattern was set.

Anybody happens to know if this is feasible or how can I do?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried looking for that information in the dygraphs documentation? (aka have you upheld [your part of the bargain](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?)

Comment: Looks like the `strokePattern` option gets applied within `linePlotter`, but `smoothPlotter` doesn't implement this feature. Pull Requests welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and modify smooth-plotter.js

add:

```
ctx.setLineDash([7, 2, 2, 2]);
```

before:

```
ctx.bezierCurveTo(lastRightX, lastRightY,
          controls[0], controls[1],
          p1.canvasx, p1.canvasy);
```

my solution:

**smooth-plotter.js**

```
let strokePattern = null;
let smoothCoef = 1/3;

const lib = (function() {
  "use strict";

  var Dygraph;
  if (window.Dygraph) {
    Dygraph = window.Dygraph;
  } else if (typeof(module) !== 'undefined') {
    Dygraph = require('dygraphs');
  }

  /**
   * Given three sequential points, p0, p1 and p2, find the left and right
   * control points for p1.
   *
   * The three points are expected to have x and y properties.
   *
   * The alpha parameter controls the amount of smoothing.
   * If α=0, then both control points will be the same as p1 (i.e. no smoothing).
   *
   * Returns [l1x, l1y, r1x, r1y]
   *
   * It's guaranteed that the line from (l1x, l1y)-(r1x, r1y) passes through p1.
   * Unless allowFalseExtrema is set, then it's also guaranteed that:
   *   l1y ∈ [p0.y, p1.y]
   *   r1y ∈ [p1.y, p2.y]
   *
   * The basic algorithm is:
   * 1. Put the control points l1 and r1 α of the way down (p0, p1) and (p1, p2).
   * 2. Shift l1 and r2 so that the line l1–r1 passes through p1
   * 3. Adjust to prevent false extrema while keeping p1 on the l1–r1 line.
   *
   * This is loosely based on the HighCharts algorithm.
   */
  function getControlPoints(p0, p1, p2, opt_alpha, opt_allowFalseExtrema) {
    var alpha = (opt_alpha !== undefined) ? opt_alpha : 1/3;  // 0=no smoothing, 1=crazy smoothing
    var allowFalseExtrema = opt_allowFalseExtrema || false;

    if (!p2) {
      return [p1.x, p1.y, null, null];
    }

    // Step 1: Position the control points along each line segment.
    var l1x = (1 - alpha) * p1.x + alpha * p0.x,
      l1y = (1 - alpha) * p1.y + alpha * p0.y,
      r1x = (1 - alpha) * p1.x + alpha * p2.x,
      r1y = (1 - alpha) * p1.y + alpha * p2.y;

    // Step 2: shift the points up so that p1 is on the l1–r1 line.
    if (l1x != r1x) {
      // This can be derived w/ some basic algebra.
      var deltaY = p1.y - r1y - (p1.x - r1x) * (l1y - r1y) / (l1x - r1x);
      l1y += deltaY;
      r1y += deltaY;
    }

    // Step 3: correct to avoid false extrema.
    if (!allowFalseExtrema) {
      if (l1y > p0.y && l1y > p1.y) {
        l1y = Math.max(p0.y, p1.y);
        r1y = 2 * p1.y - l1y;
      } else if (l1y < p0.y && l1y < p1.y) {
        l1y = Math.min(p0.y, p1.y);
        r1y = 2 * p1.y - l1y;
      }

      if (r1y > p1.y && r1y > p2.y) {
        r1y = Math.max(p1.y, p2.y);
        l1y = 2 * p1.y - r1y;
      } else if (r1y < p1.y && r1y < p2.y) {
        r1y = Math.min(p1.y, p2.y);
        l1y = 2 * p1.y - r1y;
      }
    }

    return [l1x, l1y, r1x, r1y];
  }

// i.e. is none of (null, undefined, NaN)
  function isOK(x) {
    return !!x && !isNaN(x);
  };

// A plotter which uses splines to create a smooth curve.
// See tests/plotters.html for a demo.
// Can be controlled via smoothPlotter.smoothing
  function smoothPlotter(e) {
    var ctx = e.drawingContext,
      points = e.points;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].canvasx, points[0].canvasy);

    // right control point for previous point
    var lastRightX = points[0].canvasx, lastRightY = points[0].canvasy;

    for (var i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
      var p0 = points[i - 1],
        p1 = points[i],
        p2 = points[i + 1];
      p0 = p0 && isOK(p0.canvasy) ? p0 : null;
      p1 = p1 && isOK(p1.canvasy) ? p1 : null;
      p2 = p2 && isOK(p2.canvasy) ? p2 : null;
      if (p0 && p1) {
        var controls = getControlPoints({x: p0.canvasx, y: p0.canvasy},
          {x: p1.canvasx, y: p1.canvasy},
          p2 && {x: p2.canvasx, y: p2.canvasy},
          smoothPlotter.smoothing);
        // Uncomment to show the control points:
        // ctx.lineTo(lastRightX, lastRightY);
        // ctx.lineTo(controls[0], controls[1]);
        // ctx.lineTo(p1.canvasx, p1.canvasy);
        lastRightX = (lastRightX !== null) ? lastRightX : p0.canvasx;
        lastRightY = (lastRightY !== null) ? lastRightY : p0.canvasy;
        if (strokePattern) {
          ctx.setLineDash(strokePattern);
        }
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(lastRightX, lastRightY,
          controls[0], controls[1],
          p1.canvasx, p1.canvasy);
        lastRightX = controls[2];
        lastRightY = controls[3];
      } else if (p1) {
        // We're starting again after a missing point.
        ctx.moveTo(p1.canvasx, p1.canvasy);
        lastRightX = p1.canvasx;
        lastRightY = p1.canvasy;
      } else {
        lastRightX = lastRightY = null;
      }
    }

    ctx.stroke();
  }
  smoothPlotter.smoothing = smoothCoef;
  smoothPlotter._getControlPoints = getControlPoints;  // for testing

// older versions exported a global.
// This will be removed in the future.
// The preferred way to access smoothPlotter is via Dygraph.smoothPlotter.
  window.smoothPlotter = smoothPlotter;
  Dygraph.smoothPlotter = smoothPlotter;

});

export default (pattern = null, smooth = 1/3) => {
  strokePattern = pattern;
  smoothCoef = smooth;
  lib();
}
```

and import this file into your js code

```
import smoothPlotter from '<modified smooth-plotter.js path>';
```

call:

```
smoothPlotter(window.Dygraph.DOT_DASH_LINE, 0.5);
```

options for dygraph:

```
{
        ...
        series: {
            value: {
                plotter: window.smoothPlotter,
                strokeWidth: 2,
                drawPoints: true,
            }
        },
        ...
};
```